Wordpress deployed on cluster return 408 for large headers instead of 200 or 400
I have [bitnami/wordpress] deployed on my Kubernetes cluster with default Apache configuration. My browser sends large cookies in the header to the WP website because the domain is co-located with a cookie domain containing a set size of 20kb.
If I add the line LimitRequestFieldSize 32768 to the Apache configuration, I can theoretically send 32kb of header data.
For smaller header sizes, LimitRequestFieldSize 16k, the Apache server responded with 200 if the header was under the limit and 400 if it was over the limit. However, for LimitRequestFieldSize > 16k and above, I only got 408 HTTP status codes back, with no error logs showing why.
I assume that there are some php or WordPress limitations that could be in play.
My header is at least 20k, and I can't make it smaller. No external proxy limitations are in effect.
The command I used is:
curl -vk -H "X-Header: $(cat file16k)" https://url-to-my-wordpress:8443/wp-login.php
and I expected: 200, but I got 408.
TL;DR

If LimitRequestFieldSize <16k (e.g. 12k) and cookie_size <12k (e.g. 8k) => 200 status.
If LimitRequestFieldSize <16k (e.g. 12k) and cookie_size 13k => 400 status.
If LimitRequestFieldSize >16k (e.g. 20k) and cookie_size 13k => 200 status.
If LimitRequestFieldSize >16k (e.g. 20k) and cookie_size 18k => 408 status (immediately returned).

(408 status (immediately returned) if cookie_size >16k and LimitRequestFieldSize >16k, therefore, setting LimitRequestFieldSize above 16k does not help. The change in the response code may indicate that a downstream consumer of the request rejects handling it.)

This is not a programming question. And it took me about 15 seconds to find documentation for the LimitRequestFieldSize directive "Limits the size of the HTTP request header allowed from the client"

@miken32 please, always read the post before responding. The OP considered updating LimitRequestFieldSize and confirmed that it works, but only up to a point. After Apache handles the request properly, another runtime downstream, for example, PHP or WP rejects the request or code path. It is also not clear whether this is an issue with a system (Apache) or code (PHP or WP).

You might want to use a DDOS provider like Akamai or CloudFlare in the the future and they allow a maximum headers size of 8k and 16k respectively. See the links I provided in the previous sentence. In general it is just a very bad idea to overload the headers like this.

@Dyin "It is also not clear whether this is an issue with a system (Apache) or code (PHP or WP)." It is clearly a system issue because 408 means Request Timeout. Try using curl to access a static resource instead of WP and you will most likely observe the same behavior.

@Dyin "for LimitRequestFieldSize > 16k and above, I only got 408" Do you mean you always get 408, even if the header is small? Or only when the header is > 16k?

@Olivier thank you for considering this issue! I improved the OP based on your comments. Let me know if we can provide more data for you.

Why is the OP not addressing comments or making edits to their post?

Tried the same test via localhost? What does the error log say?

Do you have the same issue with a browser? Or only with curl?

First off, 408 error is actually a request timeout.
E.g. copying text directly from the website https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/http-408/, we see the
following:

There are a handful of potential reasons behind the HTTP 408 request
timeout error. These causes include:
Network latency Clients timing out Servers being too busy to handle
the request The 408 Request Timeout error means the request you sent
to the website server took longer than the server was prepared to
wait. It can happen due to heavy traffic on the internet or a slow
connection on your side.
The problem with this status code is that it can occur for both
client-side and server-side-related reasons. In other words, although
the 408 error is categorized as a client error, this doesn’t
necessarily mean the issue stems from the browser or device. It’s
possible that the server is misconfigured or isn’t handling requests
correctly.

I additionally hope, that this error is potentially not being caused by some reverse-proxy in the middle - but let's assume and debug that it's the apache server.
Steps to fix/debug
Try the following:
Increase the Apache Timeout
Increase the Timeout and ProxyTimeout settings in the Apache configuration.
TimeOut 600
ProxyTimeout 600

See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html
Adjust the buffer Sizes:
Increase the buffer sizes for request headers and bodies to handle large headers more efficiently.
LimitRequestLine 32768
LimitRequestBody 32768

Check your PHP Configuration:
Check php.ini settings for limits related to input processing:
max_input_time = 600
request_terminate_timeout = 600

Add debugging params / enable debugging
Enable detailed logging in your Apache to get more insights into why the 408 status is being triggered.
apache
LogLevel debug

If all the above fail, do look into your reverse proxies and downstream services.
Check their configurations, and specifically to see if they can handle large headers and have appropriate timeout settings.

I suggest you to work on Apache Configuration, PHP Configuration and WordPress Configuration to handle the large headers beyond a certain size.
As you are on [bitnami/wordpress], so Apache configuration file might be in this path:
Apache Configuration
sudo nano /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

Add the required directives under the appropriate section. You might want to add them near the top of the file or under the  section.
LimitRequestLine 8190
LimitRequestFields 100
LimitRequestFieldSize 32768
LimitRequestBody 0

This will list the loaded configuration and current modules. Make sure there are no errors or warnings.
PHP Configuration:
You need to apply the following changes in the PHP.ini to handle the limitations on the size of the request header.
post_max_size = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 32M
max_input_vars = 3000

Enable Error Logging in PHP:
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
log_errors = On
error_log = /path/to/php_error_log

Enable Error Logging in httpd.conf:
LogLevel debug
ErrorLog /path/to/error_log

Timeout Configuration:
Apache  (/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf):
Timeout 600
ProxyTimeout 600

PHP (in PHP.ini)
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600


Restart the Apache Server to apply the changes:
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache

Verify the Changes
apachectl -M
apachectl -S


Use CURL for Testing
curl -vk -H "X-Header: $(cat file20k)" https://url-to-my-wordpress:8443/wp-login.php

In case of problem, review the logs

Cause:
Likely a limitation with downstream component (proxy) or PHP configuration.
Solution:
Check for Proxy: Look for a proxy server in front of WordPress and adjust its header size limit if necessary.
Examine php.ini:

Increase post_max_size to accommodate larger headers.
Consider raising max_input_vars if cookies are encoded as individual variables.

Remember:

Large cookies can impact performance. Optimize them if possible.
Be cautious when increasing php.ini values (memory usage).

